# How to update a column value in dataframe if there is any missing value in specific column range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` with `80000 rows` and `121 columns`. I would like to update the last column values/change all values in last column to 999, in the conditions **where any row in my data for columns 3 to 120 has a missing value** (even one missing value).

For example, the expected result would be this

```
    Column 1 Column2 Column 3. Column 4......Column 120 Column 121
Row 1. 123    456.    244.      NA.            3434.       999 #Update Column 121 value to 999
Row 2  123.   NA.    444.      455            4545.       0   #Do not change existing value here
Row n. 123    343.    NA.     234            3434         999 #Update Column 121 value to 999
```

Any help in this regard is much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isna().any(1)`:

```
df['Column 121'] = np.where(df.iloc[:, 2:-1].isna().any(1), 999, df['Column 121'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[df[df.columns[2:120]].T.isna().any(), 'Column 121'] = 999
```

As @QuangHoang mentioned, passing `axis=1` to `any()` would eliminate the need for `T`:

```
df.loc[df[df.columns[2:120]].isna().any(axis=1), 'Column 121'] = 999
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is T here please?

Comment: `any()` by default works on columns. Passing `1` like my answer makes it works on rows. Or you can transpose the dataframe with `T`.

Comment: [`T` transposes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas.DataFrame.T) the rows and columns.

Comment: @QuangHoang good point, I forgot the axis.  I'll update a variant of my answer based on your feedback (but yours pretty much covered the case)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:,3:120].isnull().sum(axis=1)>0, 'Column 121'] = 999
```